# ¿Cómo deshabilito tls 1.1 en tomcat 9?

Tags: java, servidor, tomcat, ssl

Estoy desarrollando un sitio web. Al momento de testear la URL para conocer las vulnerabilidades, sale la siguiente: 'TLS 1.1 is enabled'. He intentado diferentes soluciones que he encontrado en la web, modificando el archivo server.xml. El que tengo actualmente es este:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" maxThreads="1024" maxConnections="16384" SSLEnabled="true">
                <SSLHostConfig protocols="all">
                    <Certificate certificateKeyFile="[path-key] 
                   certificateFile="[path-cer]"
                   certificateKeyPassword="[password]"
                   type="RSA" />
                </SSLHostConfig>
  </Connector>
```

He cambiado el valor del atributo que dice `protocols` por la TLS 1.2 pero no funciona. Igualmente he usado el atributo `setEnableProtocols` y tampoco me ha servido.

Espero puedan guiarme con alguna experiencia que hayan tenido con esto.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

¿Y si pruebas con la v1 y v2 de TLS?

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       maxThreads="200" SSLEnabled="true">
<SSLHostConfig protocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2">     
<Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/keystore.jks" 
                 type="RSA" />
</SSLHostConfig>
```

Sino se puede probar cambiando el conector junto con el protocolo

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
     maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true"
     keystoreFile="keystore.jks" keyAlias="alias"
     keystorePass="passw"
     clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Si te sirve de ayuda hay una guia la cual indica como configurar de una manera predeterminada en: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html
Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Es simple. En la configuración del conector, pones el atributo `sslEnabledProtocols` para indicar específicamente qué protocolos SSL permites usar.

```
<Connector port="8443" 
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" 
    maxThreads="1024" 
    maxConnections="16384" 
    SSLEnabled="true" 
    sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2">
    ...
</Connector>
```

Un ejemplo de la que uso en una aplicación actualmente, que incluye varios parámetros relacionados. Yo dejo TLSv1.1 y TLS1.2 porque no deja hacer fallback a TLSv1 o SSLv3 y porque uso Java8, así que nada de TLSv1.3 aún.

```
<Connector port="443"
               server="MyCoolServer"
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               enableLookups="false"
               connectionTimeout="1000"
               maxThreads="45"
               acceptCount="5"
               minSpareThreads="15"
               SSLEnabled="true"
               scheme="https"
               secure="true"
               clientAuth="false"
               sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="path/to/keystore"
               keystorePass="myPass"
               keystoreType="JKS"
               sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2"
               useServerCipherSuitesOrder="true"
               ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
                        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
                        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
               ...
               />
```

Edito: Como a veces los elementos SSLHostConfig son un poco problemáticos, pon los datos del keystore dentro del elemento connector

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Agregué ese parametro y el servicio no inicia... Ya lo había probado antes. Alguna otra recomendación?

Comment: @soto30andres No habías indicado que lo habías probado. Y qué error sale en el log de tomcat cuando lo inicias con ese parámetro?

Comment: Esta es la excepción que sale en el tomcat 'Multiple SSLHostConfig elements were provided for the host name [_default_]. Host names must be unique.'

Comment: Ese es un problema no relacionado con el nuevo parámetro: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135892/tomcat-8-5-server-xml-multiple-sslhostconfig-elements-were-provided-for-the-ho

Comment: Añadí una sugerencia que resuelve ese otro error. Mira de nuevo el ejemplo que puse para no usar SSLHostConfig y edita tu pregunta si pruebas algo nuevo y encuentras otra cosa (así sabemos si tu nueva prueba es valida o tiene errores)